What is the minimum number of crossings of this graph? (Blood on the Clocktower jinxes)
In the game Blood on the Clocktower, players take the role of one of many different characters. What the characters do isn't important for this question. Just know that some pairs of characters don't work well together or create counterintuitive gameplay results, so the publisher creates an additional rule called a "jinx" to make them work more smoothly.
Here is a list of all the jinxes in the game, and here is what that list looks like as a graph, simplified to remove characters that are only jinxed to one other character (i.e. nodes of the graph that are only attached to one other node):

(Yes, I know this diagram is a mess, but the whole point of the question is to make it look cleaner!)
When making this graph I realized it wasn't planar about halfway through. How can I find its minimum number of crossings? Here is the GeoGebra file I used to make this screenshot so you can play around with it.

Just a comment: determining the crossing number of an arbitrary graph is NP-complete, so this should be expected to be very difficult to figure out efficiently.

But, @LieutenantZipp, the number $n$ of vertices in this graph is not enormous. Way beyond doing by pencil and paper though, that’s for sure.

@PaulTanenbaum Of course- I was just saying it'd no doubt at least require a computer for its 44-ish vertices. I don't know how long the algorithms would take, but this problem would definitely need more than a single human could do.

@LieutenantZipp Can you point me to software that can compute minimum crossings?

@PurpleP Unfortunately I'm not familiar with such a program. Also, even assuming one does exist, there would almost certainly be two caveats: 1. such a program would almost certainly only really be able to compute the rectilinear crossing number, and 2. for a graph your size it would almost certainly resort to heuristics and "close" solutions that may wind up having somewhat more crossings than the theoretically optimal solution. If either of those would be a problem for you, I would judge the search just that little bit harder. Nevertheless, best of luck!

@PurpleP Your graph has about $20$
vertices of degree $2$. If you smooth the vertices of degree $2$ and then replace the multiples with a single edge, the new graph will look much simpler. The number of crossings of the graph which is obtained after the smoothing operation does not change. Removing multiple edges changes this number, but it seems to be by an understandable rule.
